# How to $_GET [' '] value from $document->addStylesheet() in mod_modulenamet/mpl/default.php to css.php file of joomla module

Tags: php, css, joomla, module, get

Im trying create module for joomla 2.5 but i have error need everyone help me.
I have scripts in tmpl/default.php file:

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
$baseurl = JUri::base();
$module_names="modules/mod_mymodule/assets";
$url=$baseurl.$module_names;
$module_id= $module->id;
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addStylesheet($module_names.'/css/css.css.php?module_agallery_id1='.$module_id);
$document->addStylesheet('modules/mod_mymodule/tmpl/css.css.php?module_agallery_id='.$module_id);
```

And in css.css.php file i want get value of "module_gallery_id" in $document->addStylesheet above. I tried use like this in css.css.php file but i can not get module_agallery_id. please see code bellow in my css.css.php file:

```
  header("Content-type: text/css; charset: utf-8");
  echo $mid = $_GET['module_agallery_id']; // i can't get this
```

Everyone know it please let me know. I'm working on joomla 2.5.x.

Thank you so much and Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

I think you're totally confused with style sheet adding system of Joomla.
You can work like this way. your `css.css.php` is a `php`  file so why are you trying to add to the header.

keep the file as `php` and include that to the module.

In your `css.css.php` file have the following code.

```
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
echo $module_id;
//If you need to add custom css on this page try like.
$css_styles = '.my_testclass{color:#FFF;}';
$doc->addStyleDeclaration($css_tyles);
```

Then On your module file instead of adding style sheet include the page like below.

```
$module_names="modules/mod_mymodule/assets";
require_once(JPATH_SITE.'/'.$module_names.'/css/css.css.php');
```

Hope it helps..

Comment: Thank you, i know this ways, but i want use method $_GET of PHP language for get module_id form <link ref"stylesheet" href="css.php?module_id=1" />